# populate dropdown for country,state,city in codeigniter using single table only

Tags: codeigniter, dropdown

i am working on a codeigniter project where i need to populate dropdown for country,state and city but using only one table i.e., all country, state and city data should be in one table .How to do this ?

Comment: to maintain db structure you have to make 3 tables and maintain relationship between them.

Comment: as said earlier you can make 3 tables (preferred) and establish a relation between them, once this is done you can use ajax for drop down. This dropdown would be conditional dropdown i.e. if country is india the next dropdown should fetch only indian states only and so on....hence ajax is your best bet for this

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following table structure

CREATE TABLE places
(
id int NOT NULL,
country_id int DEFAULT '0',
state_id int DEFAULT '0',
name varchar(255)
);

All countries will have a default country_id and state_id of 0. The country_id for the states will be the id of a country and a state_id of 0. All cities will have a country_id and a state_id.